# How to make route work? Laravel Sluggable (Cviebrock) with category id

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel, could you push me into the right direction?

I need to render blog post on url like this `site.com/posts/1/slugged-url-of-the-post/`, where `1` is the `category_id`.

I have no problem with `site.com/posts/slugged-url-of-the-post/`, but absolutely stuck with adding one more parameter to the route and making it work. The database is okay, and I have no problems with displaying the post category_id as a text value, for example, in the posts.show blade file.

Please, help?

##### routes/web.php

```php
Route::get('/posts/{post}', function( App\Models\Post $post) {

// need to make this work:
// Route::get('/posts/{category_id}/{post}' ...

  return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
});
```

##### app/Models/Post.php

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableScopeHelpers;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Sluggable, SluggableScopeHelpers;

    public function sluggable(): array
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title',
            ],
            
        ];
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName(): string
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

}
```

Comment: You can [binding multiple Eloquent models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-model-binding-scoping) in a single route, or using controller.

Comment: Would you be so kind to show code example for my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this decision is good or not, but I came up with the following:

**routes/web.php**

```php
Route::get('/posts/{category}/{slug}', [PostController::class, 'getSingle']);
```

**app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php**

```php
public function getSingle($category, $slug)
{

    $post = Post::where('category_id','=',$category)->where('slug','=',$slug)->first();
    
    return view('posts.single')->with('post', $post);
}
```